# Can I log the searches that are returning 404 in the DB?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, custom-field, database, query

I would like to log every single search query for which one gets 404. For example, if I search Cat in the search box, but my website doesn't have any content as cats. I would like to log that "Cats" in my DB. I would like to achieve that using some codes that I can use in function.php. I have lots of plugin already, I don't wanna use any plugin. Any suggestions? Thanks!!!

Comment: note that you want your 404 pages to have as few queries as possible, with no writes, otherwise your site won't scale well. Tools such as Google search console can already track this information for you without modifying your site

Comment: If I understand the question, it won't really be a 404, because your search page exists. What *will* happen is that the search query will return 0 posts, and you should be able to log that. You could, for example, use [`is_search()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_search/) to determine if this is the search page, and [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties)'s `$found_posts` property to count how many posts were found.

Comment: Just so you know, code in functions.php is no different to plugins. Plugins are just functions.